# Facebook power law distribution - Expected number of vertices

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to figure out a power law distribution using Facebook friends as an example. Using data from 2011, supposing all users have friends in a range from 20 to 5000: the probability for each person to have d friends is p(d)=C/(d^2.2).

So, I estimated C numerically using the following equation (because the constant C is determined by the condition that the sum of probabilities from d=20 to d=5000 is equal to 1):

1 = C/(20^2.2) + C/(5000^2.2).

The probability that a vertex has degree 5000 is then

p(d) = 728.226/5000^2.2 = .000005303

I want to now find out how I would estimate the expected number of vertices with the degree 5000. Your help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: just multiply $p(d)$ times the number of nodes in your graph. With $d=5000$ in this case... If you want an estimate for the number of facebook users with 5000 friends, then you may be out of luck, since you are implicitly assuming that no user has more than 5000 friends in your model. Though, the estimate may still be tolerable.

Comment: ok, that makes sense, so 5000 * .000005303

Comment: does my calculation of C make sense? the probability of the min + max of the range equal to one?

Comment: "does my calculation of C make sense? the probability of the min + max of the range equal to one?" : Yes, for your model, since you only consider nodes in the graph with degree at most 5000, you solved for $C$ correctly, but for your other question "... so 5000 * .000005303": this is not correct, unless your sample set had exactly 5000 members (i.e. the number of users you sample is 5000). Given a group of $n$ users, the expected number of users with 5000 friends would be $n \cdot p(5000) = n\cdot .000005303$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"does my calculation of C make sense? the probability of the min + max of the range equal to one?"*
Not quite, for your model, you need to set $C$ so that $p$ is a probability distribution, that is, you set $C$ so that
$$\sum_{d=20} ^{5000} C/d^{2.2} =1$$
Which is the same as setting $C$ so that 
$$C=\frac{1}{\sum_{d=20} ^{5000} 1/d^{2.2} }$$
I plugged this sum into Mathematica and got: 
$$\sum_{d=20}^{5000} \frac{1}{d^{2.2}} =0.0235555$$
So, you have
$$C=42.4529$$

To answer your other question *"... so 5000 * .000005303":*

this is not correct, unless your sample set had exactly 5000 users.
Given a group of $n$ users, the expected number of users with 5000 friends would be 
$$n \cdot p(5000) = n\cdot (3.09153 \cdot 10^{-7})$$

You were pretty close though! Hope this helps.